# What is the meaning of the libtensorflow_framework.so.1 connot open error in java

Tags: java, tensorflow

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /tmp/tensorflow_native_libraries-1580881609119-0/libtensorflow_jni.so:
>   libtensorflow_framework.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

Comment: While you are correct in the answer below, and it can be fixed by downloading it manually. I believe itt should be automatically downloaded from your dependencies (org.tensorflow - tensorflow) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/tensorflow/1.14.0. So the fact that is not found indicates that something is wrong in the dependencies/configuraiton. (I have the same issues). In my case with version 1.15.0 I don't get the error.

Answer (score -1):

Download it ***

https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow_jni-cpu-linux-x86_64-1.14.0.tar.gz

and set JNI path for your IDE